# What about this inequality involving two operators?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Consider two operators $A$ and $B$ such that exists $M>0$ s. t. $\Vert A\Vert\leq M$. Moreover, let $k$ be a constant such that $\vert k\vert<\frac{1}{2}$. I want to show the following inequality
$$\Vert \left(1+k A (B-i\eta)^{-1}\right)^{-1}\Vert \leq\left( 1 - M\vert k\vert \Vert (B-i\eta)^{-1}\Vert\right)^{-1},$$
where $\eta$ is a real number and $i$ is the imaginary unit.
Could anyone please help me?
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can't you simplify it by $C := B−iη$  or $D := (B−iη)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Keith McClary, but could you be more precise?

Comment: If you have an answer to: "Consider two operators $A$ and $C$ such that exists $M>0$ s. t. $\Vert A\Vert\leq M$. Moreover, let $k$ be a constant such that $\vert k\vert<\frac{1}{2}$. I want to show the following inequality
$$\Vert \left(1+k A C^{-1}\right)^{-1}\Vert \leq\left( 1 - M\vert k\vert \Vert C^{-1}\Vert\right)^{-1}."$$ , isn't it an answer to your question?